# Extract Labels (city names, state names) with shapefiles using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, labeling, kml, google-fusion-tables

I want to extract shapefiles with labels on it using QGIS but labels cannot be extracted along with shapefiles.

Here's the image:

[image: Shapefile without Labels]

I want this as my output after extraction:

[image: Shapefile with Labels]

How to do something like this in QGIS? I want to upload this shapefiles in Google Fusion Table as KML but the Labels cannot be extracted?

Or, can you recommend me another software to do this?

Answer (score 1):

QGIS version **3.24** now has the capability to extract labels for a map extent using the new "Extract labels algorithm" which may help solve your problem although I haven't tested it myself.

This explanation is taken from the changelog which can be found [here](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog324/index.html#id57):

> For 3.24 we added a new tool to QGIS’ processing toolbox: “Extract
> labels”. As its name hints at, this algorithm extracts label
> information from a rendered map at a specific extent and scale.
>
> Extracted label information include its position (as point
> geometries), the associated layer name and feature ID, as well as
> label appearance properties such as rotation, text, alignment, font
> family, size, weight, etc.
>
> The algorithm also generates a default symbol-less & labelled style
> for the output layer which allows for those saved layers to be drag
> and dropped into projects and have the label drawn exactly as they
> were exported.
>
> If a map theme is specified when extracting labels, the exported
> labels will match the visibility and symbology of that theme. If left
> blank, the project’s current visible layers will be used.